# Is "Pledge to Protect" available in the original?

Tags: civilization-5

I was playing Civilization V when my friend told me of Pledging to Protect City-States.  I don't have that button and would like to know why. I would get Gods and Kings but my friend's computer is better than mine and he runs that version very slow.

I know the expansion has Pledging to Protect, but what about the original?

Comment: I'm not in front of the game right now to take a screenshot, but I'm fairly sure you can do this in the base game.  Could it be that it gets disabled when another Civ is allied with a city-state?  Or perhaps there's a tech requirement?

Comment: I don't think it can be disabled.

Comment: It's definitely possible with the base game, but I believe you need a certain amount of influence to be have the option. I would try becoming friends or allies with the City-State and see if that allows you to make a pledge.

Comment: Well I was watching London, and they just waltzed up and found City-States and right that turn they pledged to protect all of them, they had less money than me, but I don't think they payed for Influence becuase this was 5 turns into the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can pledge to protect City-States without the Gods & Kings expansion. The mechanic changed for the expansion however, now allowing you to pledge to protect city states immediately, while before it required you to at least be friends with the city state before you are allowed to. For some reason, the AI is still allowed to pledge city states right away, even in the base game. G&K just evened the playing field in this sense, but you won't need to buy the expansion to use the mechanic.